# ML model to predict values from text (a lot of training training data)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, natural-language

I have around 1M entries of the type:

```
id | big5_openness | big5_conscientiousness | big5_extraversion | big5_agreeableness | big5_neuroticism | input_text
```

Where `id` is just the identifier of some user (it is not important), the big5 values are numbers between 0 and 100 (showing how much of each of them a person is), and the input_text is the text that is used to predict this values.
These are actual predictions, but I want to develop an algorithm that uses these predictions as training data to predict these values for an `arbitrary text`.

Here is some information on how the original predictions were made by the software that created the data:
[image]

(https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/personality-insights?topic=personality-insights-science)

Does anyone know what kind of ML algorithm I could use to train on this type of data (where the input is text, and the predictions are 5 discrete classes? For me, this immediately looks like a problem that can be solved by neural network (encode the texts somehow).
Thank you in advance, have a great day!

Comment: People assume neural networks as a starting point for some reason, but classic n-gram models or TF-IDF are also reasonable ways to represent text instead.

Comment: Okay, okay. My thoughts were encode the texts as vectors (use BERT, for example), and then input them to the neural network. What are your thoughts?